# Gradle transitive dependency resolution to alpha release?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, dependencies

in one of my project i am using Spring Boot `1.5.2.RELEASE` among other things.
Since today the build process shows some warning messages, and after a bit of drill down i found out that Gradle was retrieving the package `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` in version `1.8.0-alpha0`.

Running the `dependencies` task to get an insight on the dependencies resolved, i find lots of lines of the like:

```
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.8.0-alpha0
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.24
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.8.0-alpha0
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.24
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.8.0-alpha0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.24
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.8.0-alpha0
```

Checking on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-api%22) it seems the version `1.8.0-alpha0` is among the other "normal" stable releases, and has been added on the 7th of April.

Am i right to believe that the culprit here is the package definition of this specific version of `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` on Maven Central ?

I managed to force the dependency to `1.7.25` using Gradle's resolution strategy in the meantime.

Comment: I don't think maven repo has anything to do with it. From the full `dependencies` output, you should see some dependency (either 1st level or transitive) bringing only the new version, making all the others to "upgrade" to the 1.8.0-alpha0

Comment: Indeed, after some investigation it seems one package from our internal repo had an open dependency of the form `<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>[1.7.12,)</version>
</dependency>`. I will try to amend this and see if it solves my issue.

Comment: @sm4 you were right, after fixing the open dependency of the form `[1.7.12,)` i don't have the issue anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by *sm4*, the problem comes from one of the project dependency that had itself a dependency on `slf4j` of the form:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>[1.7.12,)</version>
</dependency>
```

The open style dependency `[1.7.12,)` was resolved to the latest version in Maven Central, which is `1.8.0-alpha0`.

We can wonder whether it's normal to have alpha releases on Maven Central, but it seems `slf4j` did that on previous versions, whereas other providers like Spring uses other repositories for *Snapshot* or *Milestone* versions.

In my case, i could fix the dependency from `[1.7.12,)` to `1.7.12`, as it's an internal package in our internal Maven repo, but if like *isabsent* you rely on external packages (like [easystream](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/)) that have those open dependencies, you will need to force the version in your **build.gradle** file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with third party library [easystream](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/) in my build.gradle

```
compile 'net.sf.jsignature.io-tools:easystream:1.2.15'
```

I have checked dependencies tree with

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

in Terminal tab. The result was:

```
...
+--- net.sf.jsignature.io-tools:easystream:1.2.15
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:[1.6.1,) -> 1.8.0-alpha0
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
...
```

**1.8.0-alpha0** is [Java 9 Modularized EXPERIMENTAL version](https://www.slf4j.org/download.html) and it seems to be incompatible with my project which is restricted by Java 8 only.
If anybody else will face it - the solution is to add:

```
def versionOverrides = [//You can add other libs with open transitive dependencies here.
        "org.slf4j:slf4j-api": "1.7.25"
]

subprojects {//Delete this line for NOT A TOP LEVEL build.gradle file
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def overrideVersion = versionOverrides[details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name]
            if (overrideVersion != null && details.requested.version != overrideVersion) {
                logger.info "Overriding dependency ${details.requested.group}:${details.requested.name} version ${details.requested.version} --> $overrideVersion"
                details.useVersion overrideVersion
            }
        }
    }
}//Delete this line for NOT A TOP LEVEL build.gradle file
```

to the **TOP LEVEL** build.gradle as it was mentioned in this [post](https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-overruling-third-party).

Comment: We hit the same issue and forced the slf4j version in the init.gradle.

Comment: Looks like you have the same open dependency `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:[1.6.1,)` i have on my internal package. It seems slf4j alpha releases have always been on the Central repository, whereas for some other packages like Spring the SNAPSHOT or Milestone releases are on different repositories. I'm wondering whether only Gradle is resolving `[1.6.1,)` to the `1.8.0-alpha0` or is Maven doing this too ? I don't use Maven so can't really test this.

Comment: @gotson I do not use maven too :(

Comment: @isabsent i added the few lines you need in build.gradle, a bit more simple but less generic than the code you used

Comment: @isabsent sure, in the allprojects closure: `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'}}`  or whatever version you want to use.